# Receiving Firebase Cloud messages in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to make a client written in Node.js to receive Firebase Cloud messages?

I browsed through the Google Firebase Admin module for Node.js but didn't find a way to register my script as a client.

Also, I have seen that Google can be connected via a XMPP. Can I use this for receiving messages?